# To remove "#" character and print the rest (including those without the character "#" ) from the configuration file

Tags: bash, shell

EXPECTED:

```
Input:
###
# comment
###
var1=/opt
#var2=/app

Output:
comment
var1=/opt
var2=/app
```

I've tried running some codes but it doesn't print in the actual order:

```
grep "var1" cf.cfg
grep "#" cf.cfg | cut -d "#" -f2

Output using these codes:
var1=/opt

comment

var2=/app
```

Comment: `cat someFile | sed 's/#//'` for simple stuff. But in your expected output it even deleted space before `comment`. Is that needed too?

Comment: @SašaZejnilović you can use `sed` directly on the file, no need for `cat` (`sed` will not touch the file as long as the `-i` option is not passed).

Comment: Works fine, thanks a lot.....but it'll be better if there are no spaces among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command.

```
sed '/^[ #]*$/d;s/^[ #]*//' cf.cfg
```

It removes..
Line having only `#` or space of any combination.
From start of line, `#` or space of any combination, including line as `# # comment`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed -e 's/#\s*//;/^\s*$/d' yourfile
```

This will remove the `#` character and subsequent whitespace (`s/#\s*//`) and print lines containing non-whitespace characters (`/^\s*$/d`).

In the case of a line of the form

```sh
var=1 # this is a comment
```

the above line will print

If you want to remove the characters before the `#`, you can use

```sh
sed -e 's/^[^#]*#\+\s*//;/^\s*$/d' yourfile
```

```
var=1 this is a comment
```

This will remove all text up to the first `#`.